# Check, if generated matrix already exists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, data-generation

for a machine learning project i generate random matrices. A new matrix, which does not exist yet, is stored in an array. If a matrix is created that already exists, it should not be added. So far I do this with a loop and the allclose function of numpy to compare each matrix in the array with the actual created random matrix. However I need 500000 matricesand he code would take correspondingly long.
Do you know a better solution to compare a matrix with each matrix in an array?
I would be grateful for any help.
Here is my actual code:

```py
import numpy as np
 
a_total = np.zeros((1,3,3))
while j < 500000:
    atol = 1e-06
    h = 0
    a_add = np.random.rand(3,3).reshape(1,3,3)
    for y in range(a_total.shape[0]):
        mask = np.allclose(a_total[y], a_add, atol)
        if mask == False:
            h+=1
    if (h==a_total.shape(0)):
        a_total = np.concatenate((a_total, a_add), axis=0)
        j=+1
```

Comment: One suggestion is to use a less strict check before the full element-wise check, for example, just check equality of the first element of the matrices (up to a tolerance), and only if that's different, perform the full element-wise check to ensure all elements are different before appending

Comment: If this is for some kind of Monte Carlo simulation however I do wonder why you would get rid of scenarios that are identical to earlier ones as that would alter the statistical property of the process you are trying to simulate - I know this is not your question so just a thought...

Comment: Add a variable 'a = 8.0000001' in your code. After generating a matrix, calculate sum of matrix. Then change any one of the elements of matrix equals to 'a-sum'. Then increment a as 'a+=0.00000001' and continue. This way, all your matrix will be unique. Depending on number of matrix you could add more or less zeros in 8.00000001.....

Comment: Make sure you are using float64 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the random arrays are only for the sake of the example, because the probability of getting a single duplicate in n=500000 entries of 9-element arrays is `1e-6**9*n**2 = 1e-43`, which is vanishingly small.

If your code seemed to run forever, that's because of this line:

```
    j=+1
```

Which should probably have been `j += 1`. Also, this:

```
    a_total = np.concatenate((a_total, a_add), axis=0)
```

is a slow operation - it will copy the entire array. Instead, you should preallocate.

The most efficient way is to create a hash or hashable object from your arrays and store those.

```
import numpy as np
n = 500000
 
a_total = np.zeros((n, 3, 3))
seen = set()
j = 0
atol=1e-6
q = int(0.5/atol)

while j < n:
    a_add = np.random.rand(3,3)
        
    a_int = (a_add * q).astype(np.int32).ravel()
    a_bytes = a_int.tobytes()
    if a_bytes in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(a_bytes)
    a_total[j, :, :] = a_add
    j += 1
```

This will run in a few seconds. This is not exactly the equivalent to your requirement, because with atol=1e-6, 1.9e-6 and 2.1e-6 (difference 0.2e-6) will be counted as different, whereas 2.1e-6 and 3.9e-6 (difference 1.8e-6) will be counted as the same. But maybe this is acceptable for your application.

If the memory for `seen` is an issue, you could consider using `hash(a_bytes)`, which is a 8-byte hash (compared to 36 bytes for storing the entire array). I doubt that it's worth the trouble for 3x3 arrays, but you could consider it if your actual use case has larger arrays.